# Is there a way to render a html page from a jsp by just using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page that contains html elements. Them elements all have id's which correspond to the keys in a properties file.

As you all probably know, when the jsp loads on the server the client will be able to see the html page which is populated with .

What I want to know is if there is a way to generate html file from jsp file?

Comment: probably you need to depend on ajax

Comment: Sounds like you want a templating library. Plenty of them out there for Java.

Comment: @epascarello No I don't. I specifically stated that I want to generate html file from jsp file. Similar to the way spring uses a model.

Comment: So do a find and replace on the stuff just like a templating engine would...